# the access status of file writealllines

Tags: c#, file

I am writing some text to file using file.WriteAllLines. I want that when the WriteAllLines is writing to the file. Both other process are not allowed to read or write the file. Is it the default behavior of WriteAllLines?

Comment: when some one actualy write the file, no one else can read/write it. This is default behavior of all modern OS (as far as I can say):\

Comment: No, File.WriteAllLines() uses FileShare.Read, allowing other processes to read the file.  The odds that this causes a sharing violation in those other processes are quite low.  Most typically it will be WriteAllLines that will fail because those other processes already have the file opened and did not use FileShare.Write.  They never do.

Comment: What will happen if WriteAllLines happen first, while it is still writing the ReadAllLines happen next?

Comment: @HansPassant if you are right my answer below is a "works on my machine" thing. How can I rule that out?

Answer (score 0):

Other processes are blocked from writing to the same file since internally the `WriteAllLines` method keeps a `StreamWriter` open on the file until all lines have been written.

See the implementation detail in [the C# language reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs)

**[UPDATE]**

Reading is not possible as well, as proven with this test, which throws an `IOException` in the `readerThread`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string[] lines = new string[5000000];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                lines[i] = $"Line_{i}";
            }

            Thread writerThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                File.WriteAllLines("C:\\tmp\\wal_test.txt", lines);
            });

            Thread readerThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                File.ReadLines("C:\\tmp\\wal_test.txt");
            });

            writerThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            readerThread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Another question is, how about when I am reading a file, is that writing will be blocked? For my guessing, that should be true. If one is reading a file, and that file is being written. It will be corrupt in the content being read.

Comment: This depends what you use to read the file. If you set up the reader yourself you have several options (search for __FileMode__) to control the access. For the `ReadAllBytes` or `ReadAllLines` you can create a similar test to the one I showed above.